# Can my format be improved in anyway?

Tags: sql

```
    DECLARE
  num_of_payments NUMBER(2);        
  payment_num NUMBER(2);           
  start_date DATE;                  
  date_due DATE;                    
  monthly_payment_amt NUMBER(8,2);  
  donation_balance NUMBER(8,2);     
  pledgeamt NUMBER(8,2);            

BEGIN 
  SELECT PLEDGEAMT, PLEDGEDATE, PAYMONTHS INTO pledgeamt, start_date, num_of_payments
  FROM DD_PLEDGE
    WHERE IDPLEDGE = &IDPLEDGE;

  monthly_payment_amt := pledgeamt / num_of_payments;  
  date_due := start_date;
  donation_balance := (pledgeamt - monthly_payment_amt);
  payment_num := 0;  

FOR i IN 1..num_of_payments LOOP
  payment_num := payment_num +1;  
  date_due := add_months(date_due,1);  

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Payment number: ' || payment_num || ' Due Date: '
|| date_due || ' Payment Amount: ' || monthly_payment_amt || ' Balance: ' 
|| to_char(donation_balance,'$9999.99'));
donation_balance := donation_balance - monthly_payment_amt;

  EXIT WHEN donation_balance < 0; --LOOP until condition is met
END LOOP;
END;
```

I just want to know if my code is formatted well or should I change some things up? It works and all, just feel it looks messy and not clean.

Comment: What exactly seems "*messy*"  to you?

Comment: Should I space out the outputs to make it look more clean or is the format of it ok like that?  I just started learning SQL in class and my teacher seems very picky about formatting

Comment: This is a lot cleaner than most code I see. :-) I would recommend adding some more comments to better explain what you are doing with each step.

Comment: You search for online sql formatter

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a review of working code. Such questions belong on the Code Review Stack Exchange

Comment: To make a good [codereview.se] question you'll need to add a short description of what problem your code is solving. Other than that, @ColonelThirtyTwo is right.

Answer (score 2):

The question will probably be closed as too broad or opinion-based but I'd like to give you an example.

This is really a matter of taste. Code styles vary a lot. I will format your code using the code style which developers in my team stick to. I am not saying this is perfect, but I find it incredibly readable.

```
DECLARE
  num_of_payments        NUMBER(2);
  payment_num            NUMBER(2);
  start_date             DATE;
  date_due               DATE;
  monthly_payment_amt    NUMBER(8,2);
  donation_balance       NUMBER(8,2);
  pledgeamt              NUMBER(8,2);
BEGIN 
  SELECT PLEDGEAMT,
         PLEDGEDATE,
         PAYMONTHS
  INTO   pledgeamt,
         start_date,
         num_of_payments
  FROM   DD_PLEDGE
  WHERE  IDPLEDGE = &IDPLEDGE;

  monthly_payment_amt := pledgeamt / num_of_payments;
  date_due            := start_date;
  donation_balance    := (pledgeamt - monthly_payment_amt);
  payment_num         := 0;

  FOR i IN 1..num_of_payments
  LOOP
    payment_num := payment_num + 1;
    date_due    := add_months(date_due, 1);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Payment number: ' || payment_num || ' Due Date: '
      || date_due || ' Payment Amount: ' || monthly_payment_amt || ' Balance: '
      || to_char(donation_balance,'$9999.99'));

    donation_balance := donation_balance - monthly_payment_amt;

    EXIT WHEN donation_balance < 0; --LOOP until condition is met
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

- We do lots of spacing in declaration, be it variables or function
  arguments.
- Nested statements are indented with two spaces.
- Two consecutive statements are separated by empty line, except when they are very similar or connected (like several assignments). This part is a but fuzzy, but you get the idea.

There is always a naming convention, rules about case and other constraints, but it is a good start.